# IG CFD - difference between deal and order tabs

Tags: cfd

In IG platform CFD, what is the difference between Deal tab and Order tab? Looking for explanations and watched [How to trade CFDs | IG Explainers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oX1tw7mSq0) but could not find an explanation.

### Deal tab

[image]

### Order tab

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deal is for market orders (buy/sell at the current ask/bid) and Order is for limit/stop orders (buy/sell under certain conditions).

I can't find anything on IG's site (maybe it's in the app help?) but it's described here at about 12:00

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiWQnWnEDFQ.

Also described on their community forum here:

https://community.ig.com/forums/topic/5122-deal-v-order-on-ig-platform/